# Python - Format a list so elements are not split between lines

Tags: python, formatting, output

I wrote a program to list all the prime numbers less than a number the user inputs. When I run the program in PyCharm, the output is very nice: each number is properly situated on the line and no numbers are spread across two lines. However, when I run the program from the command line, the formatting gets weird, with numbers at the end of a row sometimes getting cut off.

Here is my code:

```
import prime_functions as pf

number = int(input("Find primes up to what number? "))
# Save primes to a list.
primes = pf.list_primes(number)

for prime in primes[0:len(primes)-1]:
    print(prime, end=', ')
print(primes[len(primes)-1])

# Print length of primes.
print(f'Number of primes less than {number}: {len(primes)}')

# Pause before exiting.
input()
```

The `list_primes` function simply checks whether each odd number from three to the user's number is prime and returns a list of all the primes it finds.

What I would like to do ideally is print a small slice of the `primes` list on each line (say, five elements per line), but I can't think of how to do that without abandoning the generality of the program and using a bunch of for-loops. Are there any Python tricks out there that will help me?

Comment: Please include your current and desired output. Also do this in any future questions where such info is relevant.

Comment: Sounds like Pycharm does word-wrapping, which a command-line doesn't. You may want to look at `textwrap.wrap`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
# Gather primes in some way.
primes = [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31]

# Group the primes.
per_line = 5
grouped_primes = [primes[i:i+per_line] for i in range(0, len(primes), per_line)]

# Print each group.
for group in grouped_primes:
    print(', '.join(str(x) for x in group))
```

#### Output

```
2, 3, 5, 7, 11
13, 17, 19, 23, 29
31
```

#### Explanation

After you gather the list of primes, group the entire list into slices of (in this example) 5 elements each. Change the `per_line` variable to change the number of primes printed on each line.

This code snippet will not handle the case when `per_line` is sufficiently large that the printed primes cause the console line to wrap.

I also shortened the printing step to one line by using `join()` on each group of primes.

You were concerned about "abandoning the generality of the program and using a bunch of for-loops," but this code snippet avoids a loss of generality and only uses one for-loop.

Comment: Very nice solution! I bet if I combine your code with textwrap, I will get exactly what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You could keep track of the index you are at and print in accordance to how many you want on a single line. Using your code for example to print five on a line like requested:

```
count = 1
items_per_line = 5
for prime in primes[0:len(primes)-1]:
    if count % items_per_line != 0:
        print(prime, end=', ')
    else:
        print(prime, end=',\n')
    count += 1
if count % items_per_line != 0:
    print(primes[len(primes)-1])
else:
    print("\n" + str(primes[len(primes)-1]))
```

The modulus operator(%) will determine if count is a multiple of 5 and if it is then the print will add a new line to the end of the prime number. 
The output of `primes = [1, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17]` will be:

```
1, 2, 3, 5, 7,
11, 13, 17
```

Comment: Agree. +1, to counteract dounvoting effect.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way to do it, using fixed width formatting and only one iteration through your list:

```
primes = [3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 47]
N = 5  # the number to print each line

print(
    ''.join(
        map(
            lambda x: " %2d\n" % x[1] if ((x[0]+1)%(N)==0) else " %2d" % x[1],
            enumerate(primes)
        )
    )
)
```

The output will be:

```
  3  5  7 11 13
 17 19 23 29 31
 37 41 47
```

The `%2d` in the string formatting says print my numbers using 2 spaces. The logic here is that you build a list of strings for printing. Every `N` digits, you add a newline (`\n`) to your string. Finally join the strings together with an empty string (`''`).

Note: `enumerate` returns a tuple of (index, value), so `x[0]` refers to the index in the list and `x[1]` refers to the value at that index.

Comment: The columns will fall out of alignment for primes greater than 99 (primes with three or more digits).

Comment: Agreed, but the user can modify the code to the desired fixed width. Or one can choose to compute the appropriate width based on the input.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a bunch of methods that print the list, nothing really stands out. I remember that at some point I've read something very nice on tabular I/O formatting, but I can't remember now.

*code.py*:

```
import sys
#import prime_functions as pf  # Decomment this line
from pprint import pprint as pp


def print_list(seq, items_per_line=5, chars_per_item=4):
    l = len(seq)
    for idx, element in enumerate(seq, start=1):
        if (idx and idx % items_per_line == 0) or idx == l:
            end = "\n"
        else:
            end = ", "
        print("{}".format(element).rjust(chars_per_item), end=end)


number = int(input("Find primes up to what number? "))
# Save primes to a list.
primes = list(range(1234, 1275))
#primes = pf.list_primes(number)  # Decomment this line (, and comment the one above)

if not primes:
    print("Empty list returned. Exiting...")
    sys.exit()

print("\n1 - Original method:")
for prime in primes[:-1]:
    print(prime, end=', ')
print(primes[-1])

print("\n2 - Elements one by one (not much of a difference):")
print(*primes)

print("\n3 - pprint:")
pp(primes, compact=True)

print("\n4 - Custom method 0:")
print_list(primes)


# Print length of primes.
print(f'\nNumber of primes less than {number}: {len(primes)}')

# Pause before exiting.
input("\nPress ENTER to exit...")
```

**Output** (truncated lines to look **exaclty** as in my (140 chars wide) *cmd* console):

> ```
> (py36x64_test) e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q47998156>"e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py36x64_test\Scripts\python.exe" code.py
> Find primes up to what number? 0
>
> 1 - Original method:
> 1234, 1235, 1236, 1237, 1238, 1239, 1240, 1241, 1242, 1243, 1244, 1245, 1246, 1247, 1248, 1249, 1250, 1251, 1252, 1253, 1254, 1255, 1256, 12
> 57, 1258, 1259, 1260, 1261, 1262, 1263, 1264, 1265, 1266, 1267, 1268, 1269, 1270, 1271, 1272, 1273, 1274
>
> 2 - Elements one by one (not much of a difference):
> 1234 1235 1236 1237 1238 1239 1240 1241 1242 1243 1244 1245 1246 1247 1248 1249 1250 1251 1252 1253 1254 1255 1256 1257 1258 1259 1260 1261 
> 1262 1263 1264 1265 1266 1267 1268 1269 1270 1271 1272 1273 1274
>
> 3 - pprint:
> [1234, 1235, 1236, 1237, 1238, 1239, 1240, 1241, 1242, 1243, 1244, 1245, 1246,
> 1247, 1248, 1249, 1250, 1251, 1252, 1253, 1254, 1255, 1256, 1257, 1258, 1259,
> 1260, 1261, 1262, 1263, 1264, 1265, 1266, 1267, 1268, 1269, 1270, 1271, 1272,
> 1273, 1274]
>
> 4 - Custom method 0:
> 1234, 1235, 1236, 1237, 1238
> 1239, 1240, 1241, 1242, 1243
> 1244, 1245, 1246, 1247, 1248
> 1249, 1250, 1251, 1252, 1253
> 1254, 1255, 1256, 1257, 1258
> 1259, 1260, 1261, 1262, 1263
> 1264, 1265, 1266, 1267, 1268
> 1269, 1270, 1271, 1272, 1273
> 1274
>
> Number of primes less than 0: 41
>
> Press ENTER to exit...
> ```

Comment: When I used pprint, it started a new line after each element.

Comment: Hmm, that's strange. Previously, I got the same effect, that's why I added the `compact=True` argument.

Comment: I really ought to investigate the docs more. I didn't know there was a compact keyword argument. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: [\[Python\]: pprint.pprint(object, stream=None, indent=1, width=80, depth=None, *, compact=False)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pprint.html#pprint.pprint)

Comment: DownVoter, could you explain yourself?

Comment: no problem, I have learned in my short time as a StackOverflow member that some people are really downvote happy. Your answer was very thorough.